# Read .dbf (Foxpro Database File) in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to access data from database with .dbf(Foxpro Database File) extension through php code and after the operation on that, they are going to store in .sql format. 
Initially I just want to access the data from .dbf extension database.
If you have a solution regarding these, then give me the steps. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [dBase Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.dbase.php) for php .

```
$db = dbase_open('/tmp/test.dbf', 0);
```